# Scrolling for WPF TabItems (not entire TabControl)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, vsto

I have the following xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Word.Addin.Presentation.MainTaskPane" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Word.Addin.Presentation" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<d:UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MyProjectPaneViewModelHandler />
</d:UserControl.DataContext>
<!--<Grid>-->

    <DockPanel Name="MainDockPanel" Background="red">
        <local:ExToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="ButtonGetHeightDimensions" Content="Show Dimensions" Height="40"></Button>
        <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="TabControl1" Background="LightSkyBlue">
            <TabItem x:Name="Tab1" Background="LightGreen"> 
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="DarkGray"/>
                        <TextBlock>Filters</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <StackPanel Name="Tab1StackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=ActualHeight}" >
                        <TextBlock FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkSlateGray" FontStyle="Normal">
                        Filters
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Button x:Name="ClearFiltersButton" Click="ClearFilters_OnClick" Background="DarkRed" Foreground="White"
                            FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" MaxWidth="124" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        Clear Filters
                    </Button>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run>Total Paragraphs </Run><Run Text="{Binding ResearchLanguageViewModel.TotalCount}"></Run>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ResearchLanguageViewModel.Filters, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Type}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBox Text="Search...."></TextBox>
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values, Mode=OneWay}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"></CheckBox>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="Tab2">
                <TabItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock>A 2nd Tab</TextBlock>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run>Mama always said lifes like a box of chocolates...</Run>
                        </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
<!--</Grid>-->
```

And the following objects....

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; set; }
}

public class ResearchLanguageViewModel
{
    public int FirmCount { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FilterViewModel> Filters { get; set; } 
}
```

I have binding setup using the INotifyPropertyChanged, etc... and all is working.  The final issue I have is with the Scrolling of the TabItem content in my first tab. The requirements call for only the tabs with overflowing content to scroll and not the entire tab control. I.e. - the tab headers should still be viewable including controls above the tab control itself and the scroll bars should appear *inside* of Tab1's TabItem area.  I've played with this for hours to no avail.  I'm obviously doing something wrong here and could use some assistance.

A bit more detail:  The binding on the CheckBox(es) / ItemControls on the Values collection can have upward of 200 - 500 controls and thus causes everything to get knocked out of wack.

Comment: A `TabItem` refer to the tab header and the content, so just to clarify, you want to scroll the content. please advise.

Comment: Yes, I would like to scroll the area that contains the checkboxes only (the content).  The Tab headers, etc... should all be left alone. But the StackPanel and all it's children should be scrollable. From the ScrollViewer on down.

Comment: Your existing code snippet is correct and it is working as expected. What is the exact issue you facing then?

Comment: It's not working on my end. One other thing to mention is that this is sitting inside of a VSTO taskpane.  Maybe that's the issue.  The issue I'm seeing is a scrollbar on the right side which scrolls all the content in the UserControl.  When only the content in the StackPanel should be scrolling. When I check the dimensions they go from 500px to ~5000 for the stackpanel.

Comment: And the scrollbar is generated by the UserControl and not the ScrollViewer from what I can tell. If I remove the ScrollViewer control the scrollbar will still appear after loading the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of a `Grid` container instead of `StackPanel`, I attempted to make a sample for you

sample

```
        <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer1"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid Name="Tab1StackPanel">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock FontSize="24"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           Foreground="DarkSlateGray"
                           FontStyle="Normal">
                    Filters
                </TextBlock>
                <Button x:Name="ClearFiltersButton"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Background="DarkRed"
                        Foreground="White"
                        FontSize="20"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        MaxWidth="124"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    Clear Filters
                </Button>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Grid.Row="2">
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run>Total Paragraphs </Run><Run Text="{Binding ResearchLanguageViewModel.TotalCount}"></Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ResearchLanguageViewModel.Filters, Mode=OneWay}" 
                              Grid.Row="3">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Type}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBox Text="Search...."></TextBox>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values, Mode=OneWay}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"></CheckBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

grid with row definitions of auto height behaves same like a stack panel except the last one which uses up the remaining space.

we can adjust it further to match the exact needs

Comment: Odd, still same result...  If I set maximumheight on the grid the overflow isn't viewable/scrollable

Comment: grid will take the height from its container, so setting explicitly is not necessary. is the user control is place inside another stack panel?  is it possible for you to post a working sample of your app which can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I will try and post a sample asap